# Alpha-numeric string without 'o' character

Tags: java, string, unique, alphanumeric

I have a positive Long number in Java. Based on this number I want to generate a unique alpha-numeric (case-insensitive) String. One of my requirements is not to use the letter o.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
String uniqueString = Long.toString(id, 35);
uniqueString = uniqueString.replace('o', 'z');
uniqueString = uniqueString.toUpperCase();
```

where id is the previously mentioned Long number.

Am I right that for 2 different ids different uniqueStrings always will be generated?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: As long as "id" is unique, your "random" ID will not have 'o', but your random number will have more z's than a random distribution.  Think about replacing each 'o' with a random non-'o' value.

Comment: use base 36 and not 35. 26 letters + 10 digits (0 to 9) = 36.

Comment: you are not sure to have a unique key.
for example if 1 is replaced by z1, and 2 replace by o1, and if you replace o by z your two digits 1 and 2 will have the same code z1

Comment: @FrançoisLEPORCQ that's why I'm using 35 and not 36 characters.

Comment: I do not see the link...

Comment: @FrançoisLEPORCQ and JustinKSU you both misunderstand what is going on here. Base 35 means 0-9 and a-y. Base 36 would include z. The distribution is not skewed, as o is replaced with an unused character.

Comment: ok, you're right !

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments this was less obvious than I thought so I guess I will post an answer.

[Long.toString(long i, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString-long-int-) can represent a number in bases between [Character.MIN_RADIX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_RADIX) and [Character.MAX_RADIX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX) which equal to 2 and 36 respectively. It uses the following symbols as digits:

> 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

When you do `String uniqueString = Long.toString(id, 35);` you are using base 35 and all the symbols except the letter `z` and of course as long as `id` is unique it's going to be unique in a different base as well.

Later you replace `o` with `z` this of course doesn't change anything and it's not going to cause you to have more `z`'s than a random distribution as mentioned in one comment, you are just replacing one symbol with another (the digits [might not be randomly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) depending on what `id` represents but that's a different topic).

You didn't ask but this is a good solution the only inefficiency is initially using `o` and latter replacing it with `z` instead of using `z` and not `o` as one of the digits but this is not significant, implementing it yourself in order to do it will be a premature optimization.